# How to set persistent environment variable using python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have developed a project in python using Gemini API (for Linux). Since I am not comfortable with any other person using my API key, I have made my project such that the user has to provide their API key. Currently, I am depending on the users editing the .bashrc file and exporting the environment variable themselves. Since many of them found it a bit cumbersome, I wanted to know whether there is any way to get API key as input from the user, and store it as a persistent environment variable (So that you only need to enter the API key once).

If setting a persistent environment variable is not possible using python, Please help me out with any other alternatives to achieve the above mentioned .

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really depends on your code if the environment variable is necessary, or can be supplied from anywhere else like just a CLI argument or external config file

Comment: You might want to take a look at python-decouple ( https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/ ). It allows you to decouple the configuration and settings from the code, obtaining variables from the environment, from the .env file of your project or from an .ini file.

Comment: I'm not sure what your users would see as less cumbersome than a one-time edit of their own shell configuration file. (As an aside, environment variables should be defined in `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`.)

Comment: Your problem is more "how to save some configuration" than how to set an environment variable. You could have a config file saved somewhere in `~/.config/your-app/` where you would save what the user entered in your input.

Comment: There is no portable way to do what you want to do. Even if you limit your question to a small number of environments (e.g., Bash on Linux) there are numerous problems with automatically modifying a user's shell environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables themselves aren't really 'persisent', as they are destroyed when their process ends. But you can store them in files to be accessed later, typically a `.env` file.

Create a file called `.env` which will be used to store
your environment variables. Make sure if you are using git to add the `.env` file to your `gitignore` to avoid committing your secrets. Use the python package `dotenv` to load the environment variables.

Install: `pip install python-dotenv`

Load the environment variables:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv()
load_dotenv()
```

Now, you can access your environment variables with `os`:

```py
import os
my_env = os.environ["MY_ENV_VAR"]
```

In order to write to your `.env` file using python dotenv, you can use the `setenv()` command:

```py
set_key(dotenv_path=".env", key_to_set="USER_API_KEY", value_to_set="abc123")
```

Ref: https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv

Answer (score 0):

It depends if it's an actual app or a python project to fiddle with it.
If it's a project to fiddle with, you should use .env in the project folder as other people say. If it's an actual app, you should save settings in a proper place that will work regardless the platform - in Linux it will be in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` in Windows in its place - look at the https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/